# Cannot print non-English text to the Console window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unicode, console

```
int main()
{
    wcout << L"Русский текст" << endl;
    wprintf(L"Русский текст\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This simple program doesn't print anything to the Console window (not even new lines). VC++ 2010 Console Application project. What is wrong?

Comment: Fyi, a `WriteConsole` call works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to links pointed to in [this blog](http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2011/01/display-unicode-in-windows-console.html) you need to change the font of the console and also this line:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

Comment: Now it prints `??????? ?????` - better than nothing, but still not full solution :)

Comment: @AlexFarber most likely you need to change the font of the console to some other that supports those characters.

Comment: After setting System Locale to Russian it started to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution if you don't want to change the Locale to Russian. The beta feature (use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support) does the job pretty well.