# C++ Console character display

Tags: c++

I'm using Visual Studio as my C++ IDE.

When I try to `std::cout` OEM type characters like :"  █ ░",
I get an error saying:

> " some unicode characters could not be saved in the current codepage.
>   do you want to resave this file as Unicode in order to maintain your
>   data?"

So I press "save with other encoding" and switch it to Western European(DOS)-Codepage 850,
and it displays the characters perfectly fine in console.

My question is, even though the characters are displaying for me just fine,
if I were to give the completed `program.exe` to someone, would it display the same characters I see(█), or would they see an entirely different set of characters like (Ä)?

Comment: Why not just test it yourself?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729870/cannot-print-non-english-text-to-the-console-window

Comment: @vallentin If I had another computer, I would. I did try the EXE and it displayed fine, but It's probably only local according to an answer below.

Comment: @ Alex Farber Thank you, not quite what I needed to know though.

Comment: If you don't have another computer, create virtual computer. For example, using VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. If their terminal uses the same encoding, then you can hope that the characters will be displayed the same way. You should not rely on this, though.

Comment: Thank you, I figured that would be so, but I wanted to be absolutely sure.